# Allow IOS Webview to run in background with polling network calls

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

We are building an IOS app with a webview control. Webview loads a react application hosted on a webserver. React application(from webview) has a short internal polling api calls to hit api server every 20 seconds to get latest data.

However, currently when the app goes to background, webview and the polling network calls are suspended. When i bring the app to foreground, it logs as network error.

How do we allow the webview to keep making polling calls even when the app goes to background?

Comment: You can't. You will need to handle the error when your app returns to the foreground and resets list the connection. This is something your web app should be able to do anyway in case of network disruption

Answer (score 1):

For this, you will have to allow the background processing of the data. In your Xcode under signing and capabilities, you will have to add background capability.

Comment: That won't help. Network polling is not a supported background mode

Answer (score 0):

Polling from the background, especially at 20s is not only a bad practice, but will probably get your app rejected. What you should do:

- remove your Interval when app WILL go to background ( use the applicationWillResignActive delegate)
- remove your Interval when this will happen
- in applicationWillEnterForeground prepare to relaunch your polling Interval

This workflow will work with quick background/foreground switches as your Interval is deleted and re-created asap.